# Градиент SVG поверх иконки Instagram из FontAwesome 5

Tags: html, css, svg, градиент, fontawesome

После обновления до FontAwesome 5 я не могу раскрашивать svgs FontAwesome.

Вот мой пример: `⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀` https://codepen.io/shadrix/pen/GygdZr

Было бы здорово, если бы это работало, как здесь: `⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀` https://codepen.io/immad-hamid/pen/jVNvQO

(Примечание: он использовал FontAwesome 4).

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Gradient over Instagram SVG of FontAwesome 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47800574/7394871) от участника  [@Philipp Mochine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7009480/philipp-mochine).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/47800574/7394871

Answer (score 3):

На иконки больше не ссылаются как на глифы шрифта, ссылаются на встроенный SVG.

Цвет содержимого иконки определяется как `fill = "currentColor"`.

Техника с установкой фона и использованием `-webkit-background-clip` больше не работает. Вместо этого вы можете напрямую установить свойство цвета. К сожалению, здесь возникают проблемы, потому что `color` не поддерживает градиенты. Вместо этого вы можете установить заливку, если используете определение градиента SVG:

```css
body{
  background: black;
}
div {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  font-size:50px;
  color: white;
}

div:hover svg * {
  fill: url(#rg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/js/all.js"></script>
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <radialGradient id="rg" r="150%" cx="30%" cy="107%">
    <stop stop-color="#fdf497" offset="0" />
    <stop stop-color="#fdf497" offset="0.05" />
    <stop stop-color="#fd5949" offset="0.45" />
    <stop stop-color="#d6249f" offset="0.6" />
    <stop stop-color="#285AEB" offset="0.9" />
  </radialGradient>
</svg>
<div>
<i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Атрибут `r` для радиального градиента не может быть выражен в тех же терминах, что и в CSS, поэтому здесь он является приблизительным.

Обратите внимание на селектор `div: hover svg *`. при наведении он перезаписывает атрибут элемента. Он должен напрямую ссылаться на стилизованный элемент, если он наследует этот стиль, `fill = "currentColor"` будет иметь более высокую специфичность.

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47801536/7394871) от участника  [@ccprog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996779/ccprog).</sub>